# How to configure the maven-release-plugin in pom to mimic -Dgoals=deploy on the command line

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to configure the maven-release-plugin's `perform` mojo **in the pom** to *only* execute the `deploy` goal (as opposed to the default `deploy site-deploy`). From the command line, it's as simple as the following:

```
mvn release:perform -Dgoals=deploy
```

Here are attempts at configuring the pom, both of which failed.

**Attempt 1:**

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>   
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>perform</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>-Dgoals=deploy -Dgit.tag.previous=</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
                    <arguments>-Dgit.tag.previous=</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    ...
</build>
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
                    <arguments>-Dgoals=deploy -Dgit.tag.previous=</arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    ...
</build>
```

Despite these changes in configuration, I'm still seeing the following log line when I do a `mvn release:perform`:

```
....
[INFO] Executing goals 'deploy site-deploy'...
[WARNING] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Building SearchService
[INFO] [INFO]    task-segment: [deploy, site-deploy]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Note the 'site-deploy' in task-segment.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: For those who want it explicitly, I used Robert Scholte's answer. Namely, I removed -Dgoals=deploy from the <arguments> tag and added the <goals>deploy</goals> tag. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking way too complex. The [perform#goals](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#goals) describes what you want. 
So it is just

```
<configuration>
  <goals>deploy</goals>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you! I read over those docs but am still so new to Maven I have difficulty with the nuances of its configuration.